# Get the returned value from managed bean in javascript

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces, jsf-2, jsf-2.2

In my application I call a Javascript event which calls a `p:remoteCommand` named `checkPageLayoutsAreSelected` as following :

```
$('selector').on('click', function (e) {
  checkPageLayoutsAreSelected();
});
```

This is the `p:remoteCommand` :

```
<p:remoteCommand name="checkPageLayoutsAreSelected" actionListener="#{beanFormDashboard.checkPageLayoutsAreSelected}" />
```

This `p:remoteCommand` will call a method in the `beanFormDashboard` managed bean which will return a Boolean value :

```
public Boolean checkPageLayoutsAreSelected(){
    for(DashboardPage dp : dashboardPageList){
        if(dp.getModel() == 0){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

So I want to get the returned value by the `checkPageLayoutsAreSelected()` from the managed bean in the Javascript code.

Something like this :

```
$('selector').on('click', function (e) {
  var returnedValue = checkPageLayoutsAreSelected();
});
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`checkPageLayoutsAreSelected` doesn't return a value or even a promise but you can Ajaxicaly return value.

```
<p:remoteCommand name="checkPageLayoutsAreSelected"
     action="#{beanFormDashboard.checkPageLayoutsAreSelected()}"
     oncomplete="getLayoutAreSelectedResult(xhr, status, args);"
/>
```

And in the method `checkPageLayoutsAreSelected()` you use RequestContext provided by PF to send result back to client:

```
public void checkPageLayoutsAreSelected() {
   Boolean result=true;
   for(DashboardPage dp : dashboardPageList){
        if(dp.getModel() == 0){
            result= false;
        }
   }
   RequestContext reqCtx = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();        
   reqCtx.addCallbackParam("returnedValue", result);
}
```

And in the Javascript callback function `getLayoutAreSelectedResult(xhr, status, args)` you will have the returned value:

```
$('selector').on('click', function (e) {
    checkPageLayoutsAreSelected();
    window.getLayoutAreSelectedResult= function(xhr, status, args) {
       var returnedValue = args.returnedValue;
       console.log(returnedValue);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm aware of this approach, which doesn't works in my case, so what I want is to get the `returnedValue` inside the event function, because in this case I'll have to create a global var in my Javascript code, and then when getLayoutAreSelectedResult get called I'll assign `returnedValue` to that global var, which won't work as `getLayoutAreSelectedResult` will be executed after the event function is finished, so I won't be able to see the `returnedValue` until the click event is fired again, which is the old `returnedValue` for the first click event

Answer (score 0):

The other answer works and gives u full xhr access, but you could theoretically do that at any point in time, throw something into the requestScope and re-render then pull it out from EL. Personally I prefer to have the elements visible on the page as we may use them later for any kind of info but this is another way to do it. Set a hidden element with reference to your bean data, and wrap it a component that can be targeted for re-rendering.

Then in your checkPageLayoursAreSelected, set the value of that object on the bean, and have the remoteCommand render/update the component wrapper of your element, and an after effect then just use basic JS or Jquery to get the value from the dom.

Working example:

view.xhtml

```
  <button type="button" id="buttonClicker" class="buttonClicker" >Click Me</button>

  <p:remoteCommand name="checkPageLayoutsAreSelected" actionListener="#{testBean.checkPageLayoutsAreSelected}" update="pageLayoutSelected" oncomplete="showVal()"/>

  <h:panelGroup id="pageLayoutSelected">
       <h:inputHidden  value="#{testBean.pageLayoutSelected}" id="checkPageLayoutValueId" />
  </h:panelGroup>

  <script>
    $('.buttonClicker').on('click', function (e) {
         checkPageLayoutsAreSelected();
    });
    function showVal() {
        alert($("[id$='checkPageLayoutValueId']").val());
    };
  </script>
```

TestBean.java

```
    private Boolean pageLayoutSelected;

    public Boolean checkPageLayoutsAreSelected(ActionEvent event) {
        if (pageLayoutSelected == null || pageLayoutSelected == Boolean.FALSE) {
            pageLayoutSelected = Boolean.TRUE;
        } else {
            pageLayoutSelected = Boolean.FALSE;
        }

    return pageLayoutSelected;
}
getters/setters
```

I've added an alert to show you that the data =has been modified.

Important, you need to likely do it in the oncomplete phase - as it's absolutely sure that the dom rendering has beenc ompleted, onsuccess the DOM may still have the older value if the JS is run quick enough.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, but when I tried to do something like this : `checkPageLayoutsAreSelected();`
`console.log($('#remote\\:checkPageLayoutValueId').val());` I always get the old value before the dom is changed as the `$('#remote\\:checkPageLayoutValueId').val()` is executed before

Comment: It has to be actioned 'after/in the oncomplete' of remotecommand, you can't use onsuccess or pre, or of course you need to re-run your javascript after the execution has happened, there is still dom in time rendering...