# sending parameters to javascript function

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2

I have a button which looks like

```
 <p:commandButton id="link" value="E-payment" action="#{controller.ePaymentMethod}"
       process="@this" update="@form" 
       oncomplete="proceedToPayment('{epaymentVo.epaymentEboCode}','{epaymentVo.token}')">
    </p:commandButton>
```

i expect ePaymentMethod to be executed first and on completion of it i am calling another javascript function which is `proceedToPayment`.

the execution order works as expected.

My `epaymentMethod` generates token and EpaymentEboCode and sets them on `epaymentVo` via setters.

My Bean class

```
class Controller
{
  EpaymemtVo epaymentVo;
    public void ePaymentMethod()
    {
        epaymentVo.setEpaymentEboCode(ebpCode);
        epaymentVo.setToken(tokenForPayment);
    }
}
```

EpaymentVo is defined as session bean

```
<managed-bean>
        <managed-bean-name>epaymentVo</managed-bean-name>
        <managed-bean-class>com.infinite.npsc.Vos.EpaymentVo</managed-bean-class>
        <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
</managed-bean>
```

now my main question is after i set token and EpaymentEboCode on my epaymentVo i expect these values to be sent as parameter to my javascript function.

so whenever i click the E-payment button for the first time null values are passed as parameter. but when i click again the the previously generated token and EpaymentEboCode are sent as paramters.

i want to send currently generated values to be sent as parameters.

Comment: Investigate in this direction: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42301606/get-the-returned-value-from-managed-bean-in-javascript/42384633. You cannot access a sort of EL/Bean values in javascript in a component like this.